# VBA Macro how to delete NOT entire row in range if specific cell has no value

Tags: excel, vba, row, cell

*Hello there. So, I have a excel table with 3 headers: Full name | Mail | Name (A1, B1, C1).



For example I've cell A2 that has no value and in that case I want to delete only A2, B2, C2 cells. If A3 cell has value, I want to keep it all(A3, B3, C3). If A4 cell has no value, I want to delete cells A4, B4, C4 and and keep it going until last row that has value in A column. I already tried to google it, I found few options but it didn't work out(most of options delete entire row). Code is probably isn't hard, but I cannot solve this puzzle at the moment ...*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below should work for your situation as described.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'get the last row with data in column A
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'loop through all rows bottom to top
For x = lastRow To 2 Step -1
    
    'if cell A in a row is blank
    If ws.Cells(x, 1) = "" Then
        
        'delete those rows of the table
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(x, 1), ws.Cells(x, 3)).Delete Shift:=xlUp
        
    End If
    
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I just would like to ask if it is possible to speed it up the process? For example. I have 50 rows and 25 A rows that has no value, it takes so long to delete these 25 rows(at least 2-3 minutes).

Comment: That's unusual: it takes less than a second to process 50 rows on this end. You might try copying just the relevant data from your worksheet to a new sheet and run it there instead. Another option is to put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the start and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end so that it doesn't need to update everything every time it deletes a row.